# Search predictions broken in Chrome - reinstall didn't solve the problem

Tags: search, google-search, google-chrome

I recently changed the default search engine to a custom google search URL (using baseUrl) with some additional parameters and removed all the rest of the search engines, and since then, the search predictions stopped working.

I even tried to reinstall Chrome but as soon as I resync, the problem is back!
Search predictions are just gone without option to fix!!

In IE changing the search provider allows specifying a prediction (suggestion) provider, In chrome, once you change the default search engine, you'll never be able to have predictions again!!
This is a terrible bug, I mean WTF!!!

**Is there any workaround to that?**

I posted a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109583) a while ago but it seems no one looks at it. I'm about to give up on Chrome and go back to IE, the only good thing about Chrome is the Extension market and the AdBlocker (which I can find in IE as well). The perfrormance changes don't matter to me too much.

Thanks

Comment: Not that that would help you any further with your issue, but I would recommend you keep the swearing to a minimum and punctuation to the appropriate level when reporting bugs. It helps to get taken more seriously.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg OK makes sense, tx sry, but do you agree that this is a blocking issue??

Comment: Shimmy please don't use SMS abbreviation here like tx or sry.

Comment: @avirk, I was typing it from my phone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto:

[Stop sync and remove all of your
    synced data](http://chromestory.com/2011/01/how-to-remove-erase-passwords-your-chrome-synced-data-from-google/).

After relaunching Chrome, the problem should be solved.

Comment: how will this help him? He has stated that after he syncs, predictions are lost. This will still sync his search method, which will break prediction again.

Comment: @Zac I've tried the solution again, seems I've missed part 2. Although a very frustrating solution, did work. Anyway no need. to follow the entire guide, just step 2.

Answer (score 0):

The "stop sync and remove all synced data" trick worked for me.  Unfortunately the steps have changed slightly and it is now "Disconnect Google Account" > choose YES to remove all data.  I shut down Chrome (and the 8(!!!!) instances still running in Task Manager, then just re-launch Chrome and re-sync and it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

After trying @ZacB's suggestion, it still didn't work. [Removing all Chromium's settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/103188) and rebooting the computer also didn't work, so I concluded that the Chromium version I was running must be buggy.

Updating Chromium fixed it for me.